# Hot observable without a subject

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, subject

Is there a way to create a hot observable without using a subject? For instance, to provide an event-style observable you might use a subject:

```
class MySouce
{
    private Subject<string> thingsSubject = new Subject<string>();
    public IObservable<string> ThingsThatHappen
    {
        get { return this.thingsSubject; }
    }

    private void OnThingHappening(string thing)
    {
        this.thingsSubject.OnNext(thing);
    }
}
```

I don't hate it, but I don't love using a Subject. It feels like using it is introducing extra state and lifetime management concerns. I know I could implement using `Observable.Create` and just tracking subscribers, but that feels like the exact same problem.

Is there a more elegant solution to this or am I just being pedantic by worrying about it in the first place?

---

**UPDATE**

The reason that I have even put so much thought into this in the first place. I was recently given some legacy code with types that contain events that needed to be removed and replaced with observables. All of these events were set up the same way:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent { add; remove;}

protected void OnMyEvent() { ... }
```

And then scattered all throughout that type are various calls to `OnMyEvent()`. I handed it off to a junior developer and had them replace the events with observable properties backed by subjects and have the `Onxxx` implementations push a new value to the subject. Since then, though, I've been kind of stewing over it and wondering if there is possibly another solution, given my aversion to subjects in production code.

Comment: Normally if you want to use an interface, it needs an implementation.  Just sayin.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I thought I'd put it out there just in case there is something I am missing. It feels like an antipattern.

Comment: The real question is: Who's calling OnThingHappening, and why? Maybe you need a subject. Maybe you don't. But the answer lies in the usage of this class, not in its implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. The whole idea that I was shooting for here is to be able to trigger it arbitrarily from inside the class.

Comment: So now the real question is under what conditions do you want to arbitrarily call OnNext: On some event, after a period of time on a combination of things happening? A Subject could be what you want, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: @LeeCampbell That was my exact thinking which led me to propose this question in the first place. I will add some more explanation to the question, since it feels like folks are more worried about why somebody would do that than how.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you still be more specific on what is actually calling OnMyEvent/OnNext. This what I am interested in e.g. is from an event handler, a property changed,

Comment: That's the thing, I did't really know for sure. The only thing I knew was that there was the OnMyEvent corresponding to each event. So, what I needed was the exact behavior of a subject. But, using a subject type in production code makes me feel icky. That's really the bottom line. Icky.

Comment: Mmmm I get why you see that as being the bottom line, however often when I ask for the actual line of code that is invoking the Onnext/OnMyEvent we find that it is a callback, timer or something else that easily fits into Rx without needing a subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly they are:

- Expose a public `IObservable<T>`
- Inside the class, be able to trigger its `OnNext`, `OnError` and `OnCompleted`

This boils down to needing something that implements `IObserver<T>` and `IObservable<T>`, but only exposing the `IObservable<T>` publicly. `ISubject<T>` is defined as implementing these two interfaces, and a plain `Subject<T>` is the simplest implementation of it.

Your current solution is as simple and straightforward as possible, anything else will involve reinventing a `Subject<T>` yourself.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I had; I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't being naive by assuming there was not a more elegant mechanism.